# Should MSMQ be on a sender of receiver machine?

Tags: msmq

I'm wondering if there are any guidelines for which machine MSMQ should be installed on, in a situation in which one machine (A) will be sending messages, and another machine (B) will be receiving them. Are there any factors that would indicate either that it's better to install MSMQ on A (in which case the sender writes messages locally, but the receiver reads them remotely), or to install on B (in which case it's the other way round?)

(If it makes any difference, in our case the sender is a website, and the receiver is an app server machine that sits behind the website, and to which the website sends messages. In the absence of any other advice, I'd have been inclined to install MSMQ on the app server, on the vague principle of keeping as little software as possible on the web server on security grounds, since that server is in the first line of any attack.  To complicate matters, the website sits behind a load balancer - so 'machine A' is actually two identical machines, likewise for machine 'B').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSMQ has to run on all machines that are sending or receiving messages.
It doesn't matter if you "send local/read remote" or "send remote/read local".